# "contact us" button and "reset fields" button doesn't redirect to links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a "contact" button that doesn't allow you to submit until the required fields are filled, then redirects you to another html site. It currently doesn't allow you to submit correctly, but when the fields are filled it just resets the page instead of redirecting it. I think it's ignoring the "form action" part.

Also the reset button just doesn't work at all.

Does anyone see anything that might be the reason?

Thanks!

```html
<form method="get">
  <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fmail" id="fmail" required="required" placeholder="your 
   first name"></label><br><br>
  <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lmail" id="lmail" required="required" placeholder="your 
   last name"></label><br><br>
  <label>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="your 
   email"></label><br><br>
  <label for="comments">Comments:</label><br>
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40" required="required"></textarea>

  <br><br>

  <form action="contact2.html" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Contact" />
  </form>

  <form action="contactus.html">
    <input type="reset">
  </form>

</form>
```

Here's an image of what it looks like when you click contact without filling in the fields

https://i.gyazo.com/dc3a77b5eed0dbad2d6f6e2da1cf3075.png

Comment: When a form is submitted it should be sending input data to some backend script like a PHP file that will handle the data... Also, the method should be set to "post" if you send something. The reset type of input only applies to the parent form, which in your case includes only the reset itself, so it can't reset the other fields...

Comment: Is there a way to make the contact button just check if the fields are required and also redirect to another html file?

Comment: For a proper validation you gonna need some JS, but at this point, you can use HTML5 features, add to each text input property required: <input required> or <input required="true"> and see what happens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working code

```
<form method="post" action="/abc.html">
   <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="fmail" id="fmail" required="required" placeholder="your 
   first name"></label><br><br>
   <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lmail" id="lmail" required="required" placeholder="your 
   last name"></label><br><br>
   <label>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="your 
   email"></label><br><br>
   <label for="comments">Comments:</label><br>
   <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40" required="required"></textarea>

<br><br>

       <input type="submit" value="Contact"/>

       <input type="reset">

</form>
```

Explanation:

1. All form-elements buttons, textarea, input should be wrapped in one `form` element.
2. you need to add form method as `post` and in action pass the URL of the page where you want to redirect after successful form submission.

Comment: It fixed alot of the problems so thanks! However when you click "contact" it won't redirect to contact2.html, the redirection site I want it to go to, is there a way to make the contact button also redirect to a link?

Comment: Updated code, basically you need to add form method as post and in action pass the URL of the page where you want to redirect after successful form submission.

Comment: holy wow it worked! Thank you so much I've been looking at this for atleast 2 hours now I appreciate it so much!